# MonoTouch: Three20 - command not found

Tags: binding, xamarin.ios, makefile, three20

I'm trying to get Three20 to work with MonoTouch, so I found this website:

https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/Three20

I unzip it and when I doubleclick the makefile, I get a lotta errors:

```
Last login: Mon Nov 28 21:32:41 on ttys000
MacBookPro:~ mojo$ /Users/mojo/Downloads/mono-monotouch-bindings-b98b8a8/Makefile ; exit;
/Users/mojo/Downloads/mono-monotouch-bindings-b98b8a8/Makefile: line 1: ATMHud: command not found
/Users/mojo/Downloads/mono-monotouch-bindings-b98b8a8/Makefile: line 5: all:: command not found
/Users/mojo/Downloads/mono-monotouch-bindings-b98b8a8/Makefile: line 7: ios:: command not found
/Users/mojo/Downloads/mono-monotouch-bindings-b98b8a8/Makefile: line 8: IOS: command not found
make: *** No rule to make target `build'.  Stop.
/Users/mojo/Downloads/mono-monotouch-bindings-b98b8a8/Makefile: line 9: DUAL: command not found
make: *** No rule to make target `build-specific'.  Stop.
/Users/mojo/Downloads/mono-monotouch-bindings-b98b8a8/Makefile: line 11: osx:: command not found
/Users/mojo/Downloads/mono-monotouch-bindings-b98b8a8/Makefile: line 12: OSX: command not found
make: *** No rule to make target `build-specific'.  Stop.
/Users/mojo/Downloads/mono-monotouch-bindings-b98b8a8/Makefile: line 14: build:: command not found
/Users/mojo/Downloads/mono-monotouch-bindings-b98b8a8/Makefile: line 15: DIRS: command not found
/Users/mojo/Downloads/mono-monotouch-bindings-b98b8a8/Makefile: line 17: build-specific:: command not found
/Users/mojo/Downloads/mono-monotouch-bindings-b98b8a8/Makefile: line 18: DIRS: command not found
/Users/mojo/Downloads/mono-monotouch-bindings-b98b8a8/Makefile: line 20: clean:: command not found
/Users/mojo/Downloads/mono-monotouch-bindings-b98b8a8/Makefile: line 21: IOS: command not found
/Users/mojo/Downloads/mono-monotouch-bindings-b98b8a8/Makefile: line 21: OSX: command not found
/Users/mojo/Downloads/mono-monotouch-bindings-b98b8a8/Makefile: line 21: DUAL: command not found
logout
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Mojo

Update (@jstedfast)...

I'm a Unix noob - but I think the Three20 is buggy...

```
MacBookPro:mono-monotouch-bindings-b98b8a8 mojo$ make
make build DIRS="AdJitsu ATMHud FacebookConnect GebePrinter MGSplitViewController PayPal RedLaser Tapku TestFlight Three20"
for i in AdJitsu ATMHud FacebookConnect GebePrinter MGSplitViewController PayPal RedLaser Tapku TestFlight Three20; do (cd $i; make); done
make[2]: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make[2]: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make[2]: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make[2]: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make[2]: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make[2]: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make[2]: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make[2]: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [build] Error 2
make: *** [ios] Error 2
MacBookPro:mono-monotouch-bindings-b98b8a8 mojo$ cd Three20
MacBookPro:Three20 mojo$ cd binding
MacBookPro:binding mojo$ make
git clone git@github.com:facebook/three20.git
Cloning into three20...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
make: *** [three20] Error 128
MacBookPro:binding mojo$
```

Any idea?

Comment: "I get a lotta errors" gives us absolutely nothing to go by to try and help you. Please edit your question to actually make it one that contains information we can use, or it will most likely end up being closed as not a real question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Makefile` files are scripts that needs to be execute using the `make` command. E.g.

```
cd \your-dir\monotouch-bindings\
make
```

This is part of the **README** file inside the [repository](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/Three20).

> To build the bindings, run the `make` command from within the bindings
>   directory.

Comment: I now get this error: make[2]: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Comment: That means you didn't cd into a directory with a Makefile in it.

Comment: @jstedfast - I updated my question .. I can't seam to make it work. Hmmm.

Comment: You need to get a github account so that the Three20 binding Makefile can checkout the source code for Three20

Comment: @MojoDK you're on the right track. Your last error is likely because you are not registered with **github** (or that the service had an hipcup when you tried to pull the Three20 sources).

Comment: Poupou - you were right. I needed to register (had no clue). Can you make your suggestion as a new answer, so I can set it as "Answered"? Thanks! :)

Comment: Ups sry Poupou ... I now see that jstedfast answered my question first.

Comment: Thank you guys for helping me!!!!!!! Btw is there any good samples of using Three20 with MT?

Comment: Never used myself :( The bindings are a bit new (at least the last update was) so it's unlikely you'll find a lot of MonoTouch sample using it. OTOH you can look at existing Objective-C samples and port them to MonoTouch (a good learning exercise to learn a new API). We could even add the sample code in GIT to help others as well :)